# dictionaryWithContentsOfFile and Sandbox

Tags: cocoa, sandbox

I've created a mac app that load a xml file from an user selected folder, and after using the app, the user saves a customized file (.adgf)
When i try to load the .adgf file (that is a plist file) that has the xml path within one record i call 
dictionaryWithContentsOfFile but it return me a "nil". I think the problem is the sandbox (sometime it works sometime not). The string path is correct.
Maybe when the user load the xml file should i save within of particular app "Document folder"?

Edit:
I'm trying right now the Bookmark Data solution and I retraive a NSURL but it doen't work. The code I'm using is this:

```
- (NSData *)bookmarkFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                 includingResourceValuesForKeys:NULL
                                  relativeToURL:NULL
                                          error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating bookmark for URL (%@): %@", url, error);
    [NSApp presentError:error];
}

return bookmark;
}

- (NSURL *)urlFromBookmark:(NSData *)bookmark {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark
                                       options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope
                                 relativeToURL:NULL
                           bookmarkDataIsStale:NO
                                         error:NULL];
return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user stores the file you should take the bookmark data from the URL using
`-[NSURL bookmarkDataWithOptions: includingResourceValuesForKeys: relativeToURL: error:]`

Use `NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope` for the options.

This NSData object should be stored somewhere (plist?) and when you want to read the file again in a later session you can create a sandbox compliant NSURL from the bookmark data using `+[NSURL 
URLByResolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeToURL:bookmarkDataIsStale:error:]`

Comment: I'm sure that the indication you've wrote here is correct but i've tried without success. I can save the NSURL with a NSData and retreive it back with a correct NSURL but [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:bookmarkedUrl]; return me always a nil.

Comment: Also you say "After th user stores the file", you mean after the user saves the customized file (.adgf) I've to call bookmarkDataWithOptions? But if the user saves this file for example on the desktop and the plist file is in another directory can I access to the plist file by NSURL with URLByResolvingBookmarkData?

Comment: After the user saves the file you have to call bookmarkDataWithOptions.
I thought the saved file (.adgf) was the plist? How does the plist get created?

Comment: The user open the app, load the plist and image file so i create the bookmarks storing in NSData. When the user save the work using .adgf file i write the names of the NSData's bookmark inside it so I should be able to retreive the bookmarks of plist and image loaded before. I'm able to get back the NSURLs (and these are fine formatted) from the NSData when i load back the .adgf file but when i do mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:bookmarkedUrlPlist]; it's a nil

Comment: You also need to bookmark the .adgf file as this is a file that is not saved inside your apps sandbox.

Comment: don't need to bookmark files that user handle by opening an saving by NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel.

Comment: @Cocoalover The bookmark is needed for access in future runs.

Comment: Did you set the right entitlements? Like com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope?